# It is a good practice to pass an argument which is an injectable service?

Tags: typescript, coding-style

It is a good practice to pass an argument which is an injectable service to a function?

Hi every, one I tried some research but i was not able to find an answer yet for the question above.
I'm working with angular and face some code that makes me confused what the practice to follow/avoid?

Scenario:

shopping-util.ts

```
export class ShoppingUtil {

    public static buildShopingNote(material, bService: BService) {
        if (!material) {
            return '';
        }
        return bService.doSomeThing(material);
    }
}
```

b-service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class BService {
    public doSomeThing(input): string {
        let result = 'do something with input';
        return result;
    }
}
```

I wonder if we should move the function 'buildShopingNote' to a business service instead so we can inject the BService when the service is initialized?
And Is it the same answer for other programing languages (Java, C ..) that I assume it would be the same answer?

Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you reuse the `bService` for multiple times, it is clear to move the service to the constructor of the class. However, if it is only used once, you can choose how to deal with it. In the current code, you don't even to have to create the `ShoppingUtil` class as it is not necessary to construct that class while it only has static functions. You could either create a namespace or export a function directly from the Util. Or move `buildShopingNote` to the `BService`

Comment: Thanks Thien for your quick response. Maybe I didn't explain my idea clear enough. In my case, the 'ShoppingUtil' has more than one function, and 'buildShopingNote' is doing more than that. What makes me thinking is the way we pass 'bService'. Personally, i don't like that idea, because likely we make the function 'buildShopingNote' bigger with more logic in it. And i think the dependence among Components, Services, Util classes should be: Component->Service, Service->Util, Component->Util. The inverse dependence (Util->Service) is not a good practice? What do you think?

Comment: It base on which type of Util you want to give. Service->Util makes sense if they are at the same level. But in your case, Service seems to be on a lower level, so it could be another way around